# How can I rewatch the intro movie?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I loaded up Star Wars: The Old Republic for the first time this morning and hit escape to skip the intro video. I'd now like to watch it, but now when I load the game, it skips straight past the intro video.

Is there a way to make the intro video replay?

Comment: There is a way to view them in game (Because I was in the same boat!), but I don't have access to the client atm to tell you where to go. Watch this space!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Within the game at the character selection screen, click on "Play Cinematic" (the one with the clapboard icon at bottom left):

[image]

Then your desired video

- "Hope" = Republic
- "Deceived" = Imperial
- "Return" = Intro

If you want to watch the videos outside of the game on your computer, you can use [RAD Video Tools](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkdown.htm) to play the `.bik` files in the movies directory (see below for what they're named).

**The better alternative**, as it's more convenient to share and replay as you can actually scrub through the video and replay bits (neither of which you can do with the above two methods), would be to just watch them on YouTube.

Intro (`Movies/en-us/game_intro.bik`):

Republic (`Movies/en-us/rep_intro.bik`):

Imperial (`Movies/en-us/imp_intro.bik`):